# A way to reduce the data length of argofloat data using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this argofloat data with this information:

```
NetCDF dimension information:
Name: N_POINTS
size: 94428
type: dtype('int32')

NetCDF variable information:
Name: PRES
dimensions: ('N_POINTS',)
size: 94428
type: dtype('float64')

Name: PSAL
dimensions: ('N_POINTS',)
size: 94428
type: dtype('float64')

Name: TEMP
dimensions: ('N_POINTS',)
size: 94428
type: dtype('float64')

Name: TIME
dimensions: ('N_POINTS',)
size: 94428
type: dtype('int64')
```

I want to create a Hovmöller diagram and need to make a `meshgrid` with `x_mesh` represent the time and `y_mesh` represent the pressure. the code is below:

```
x_mesh, y_mesh = np.meshgrid(time, pres, indexing='ij')

enter code here

temp_2d = griddata((time, pres), temp, (x_mesh, y_mesh), method='nearest')
sal_2d=griddata((time, pres), sal, (x_mesh, y_mesh), method='nearest')
```

and it shows me memory error cause the shape is too big `(94428,94428)`, any idea to reduce the length of the data?

By the way the data time range is from 2016-09-04 23:31:58 to 2018-12-08 21:05:27 and the data frequency is continuous.

I tried to composite the data to monthly but it created the same value of the pressure every month. I need the pressure from surface to max depth.

To make it clear what I want to make, I've already create plotted data with another float which have fewer length of data, here is the result:
[image: Salinity Plot]

Here is the function I use to make the plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,9),facecolor='white')
plt.contourf(x_mesh, y_mesh, sal_2d, cmap='jet', levels=30)
plt.colorbar(label='Salinity (ppt)')
plt.title(f'Salinity Contour Plot for Float {float_ids[0]}')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Pressure (dbar)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If your data is not on a regular grid, it may be worth looking at `tricontourf` https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html

Comment: `np.meshgrid` shouldn't be called with all the `time` and all the `pres` values, only the unique values. Often the data is already organized as a grid, and just calling `reshape(N, -1)` with the appropriate `N` (instead of `griddata` etc.) would be sufficient.  You didn't mention which function you want to use for the plot.

Comment: @RuthC Thanks for the advice, I will try to learn and using `tricontourf` function for my data

Comment: @JohanC Sorry I've edited the function I use to create the plot. By the way when im using the unique values and calling `reshape(N, -1)` its creating the data with shape (N, 1) and it cannot used to the `contourf` plot because its need to have the same shape? any advice, Thanks for helping btw!

Comment: You should either use `np.meshgrid` with the unique values. OR reshape with the original data, without `np.meshgrid` and without `np.griddata`. (N is the width of one column, not of the complete data).  Did you try `tricontourf(time, pres, sal)` which should work with your original data, without `reshape` and without `np.meshgrid` etc.

Comment: It’s also worth bearing in mind that the majority of people reading StackOverflow will not be oceanographers.  So rather than saying your data is from an Argo float, describe what that sampling looks like.

Comment: @JohanC Using `tricontouf` works fine but it needs to convert the `time` into `float64` making the x axis of the plot showing the float value, is there any way to show actual date in the x axis?

Comment: Maybe `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))` works for your date format?